# jcarousel and flow tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jcarousel

Trying to work out a problem where i need to use [Jcarousel plugin](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) along with a tooltip a simle installation of [flow player jquery tooltip plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html) worked but as i am in `circular mode` the tooltip seems to work when we scroll from left to right but when i scroll right to left the tooltip shows up but the position is far far to the right.
Here is [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/ADr5h/) if you can help me out

Comment: the jcarousel has dynamic creation and dispose of the objects when its wrap:circular, and it detaches the plugin or mixes up the top and left propeties.  Which tooltip plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using Flow player tooltip plugin

Comment: I looked at both plugins, the thing is that when items begin to repeat in the html new <li><img> items are added and the tooltip remains attached to the original. The other issue is that when the tooltip is created for the original images it removes the title attribute from the image. So it will need more coding. i can get back to it this weekend if u like. Sounds interesting.

Comment: not very interesting for me ;-) this has kept me occupied alot
thanks for your words i am trying other variants like qtips. If I can make that work along with jcarousel

Comment: did u happen to come across the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

it because css overflow:hidden; on jcarousel. hidden make disappear than the tooltip can be visible.